# Non-clickable menu items in Wagtail

Tags: wagtail

I'd like to have some main menu items which are non-clickable but their children are in drop-down menu and clickable.

I imagine an approach may be as a special type of model which is:

- parent to a few pages
- inaccessible itself

Or may be more elegant way to do it I don't suspect?

Comment: Hi - is this in Wagtail admin? Or your public facing frontend? If it is the frontend - what is your CSS framework?

Comment: This is a public facing frontend. I have no idea for the moment, this is not my part.

Comment: ok, might need a bit more info to give a constructive answer sorry, like the template code used to render the menu.

Comment: I use this approach, shorten a bit, no JQuery, no Bootstrap:
http://www.djangopaths.com/create-limitless-depth-menu-tree-wagtail-smartmenus-and-bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you are using the example code from [here](http://www.djangopaths.com/create-limitless-depth-menu-tree-wagtail-smartmenus-and-bootstrap/), this is more of a Bootstrap question but here is a potential solution.

Towards the end of the `<nav>` element you have your container that contains the main menu items.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-3">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      {% for menuitem in menuitems %}
        <li class="{% if menuitem.active %}active{% endif %}">
          {% if menuitem.show_dropdown %}
            <a href="{{ menuitem.url }}">{{ menuitem.title }}
              <span class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm visible-xs-inline">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
              </span>
            </a>
            {% top_menu_children parent=menuitem %}
          {% else %}
            <a href="{% pageurl menuitem %}">{{ menuitem.title }}</a>
          {% endif %}
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

To make the menu items not clickable, adjust the href attribute for the menu item. Instead of being `{{ menuitem.url }}` make it `#`. This will ensure the menu dropdown still works but there is no URL to take people to the 'parent' page.

```
        <a href="#">{{ menuitem.title }}
          <span class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm visible-xs-inline">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          </span>
        </a>
```

See also: [Boostrap 3 Navbar Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar)

Comment: Thank you for your advice but I eliminated all the redundant containers and Bootstrap styles to have framework-neutral code. I'm trying to develop a different approach. I created NoopPage model which raises 404 itself but may contain subpages. I added BooleanField 'noop' there to read this attribute in template to prevent rendering href for links with NoopPage behind them. I suspect there may be parent pages with child subpages which should be clickable/accessible as well. Though now that 'noop' attribute is invisible in top_menu_children template for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried getting the specific page with self.specific or page.specific? The noop attribute will only be available on on the specific instance.

Comment: I eliminated 'noop' attribute and relay on seo_title field which is filled with 'noop' string for this (Noop) page on saving by default. It works for the moment. I'll see if it will play well with further front-end.

get_children() returns Page model itself, not those pages inherited from it. That's why my .noop was unavailable.